# Writing a text over an image that is on top of another image using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, bots, discord

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageOps
```

Command:

```
    font1 = ImageFont.truetype('timesbd.ttf',17)

    backgtound = Image.open('plan.png')
    bar = Image.open("bar.png")
    write = ImageDraw.Draw(bar)
    write.text(xy=(73, 181), text="{} / 20".format(numbertotal), fill=(255, 255, 255), font=font1)
    background.paste(bar, (2, 173), bar)
    background.save('plan2.png')
```

I have a picture called "bar" on top of an image called "plan", I'm trying to write a text over the image "bar" but the text is not on top of the second image, only the first one, could anyone help me? (the x,y coordinates are correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, and that you want the text to be over the image `bar`, the issue is that you are writing the text after you paste. Instead, you can first write your text on the image `bar`, then paste it into `background`.

In this example, `plan.png` is the dog and `bar.png` is the cat. You can see that the text is on top of `bar`, and not on top of `plan`:

```
font1 = ImageFont.truetype('timesbd.ttf',17)

background = Image.open('plan.png')
bar = Image.open("bar.png")
write = ImageDraw.Draw(bar)
write.text(xy=(79, 181), text="my text", fill=(255, 255, 255), font=font1)
background.paste(bar)
background.save('plan2.png')
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the question according to what you wrote, but even so the text does not stay on top of the second image, why?